# use docker-compose up, docker container not start

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try `docker-compose up -d`
I want virtual computing system in docker container

This is docker-compose.yml code.

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  vhost1:
    container_name: vhost
    image: ubuntu
    restart: always
```

This is docker status

```sh
➜   docker ps                    
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                                  PORTS                                       NAMES
0cbccb43e414   ubuntu:20.04                         "bash"                   4 seconds ago   Restarting (0) Less than a second ago                                               vhost
```

what is problem?..

Comment: Look at `docker logs 0cb`.

Comment: Do you have a Dockerfile or any other sort of image you can run?  It doesn't usually make sense to run the unmodified `ubuntu` container; anything you change there will get lost as soon as the container exits.  Docker's [Sample application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial walks through a typical workflow.

Comment: I Can`t looking at the docker log.   
Not starting..

Comment: I don't have Dockerfile. I used ubuntu images at docker hub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't running a service. The Ubuntu base image ships with the entrypoint set to a shell. That shell will exit when it reaches an EOF on stdin, which is immediately for a non-interactive container. So the fix is to package the application/service you want to run in the container.

If you only want to leave a container running with nothing inside, `tail -f /dev/null` is a common noop.

It also looks like you intend to treat a container as a VM. I'd recommend reconsidering that since these are two different tools solving different problems. Containers are designed to package and run an application.

Comment: Interesting; I've never used the `tail`. I usually use `sleep` and add `command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "sleep 3600"]` to `docker-compose.yml` for temporary containers.

Comment: Thank you.  This problem is solution. add stdin_open in docker-compose.